# Python Bokeh Bar Chart - Modify Legend Box

Tags: python, bar-chart, legend, bokeh

I am creating a bar chart using Bokeh.Charts.Bar. My problem is that, I have a legend box of 15 labels, and this legend box is covering the right most column (I am using legend='top-right', it would be the same if I change it to 'top-left', it would cover the left most column). So I am trying to create a legend object (bokeh.models.annotations.legend) to set background_fill_data = 0, label_standoff, legend_pedding etc. in order to move the legend box around or make it transparent so that it is easier to create the chart. However, I have achieved nothing so far. Help is really appreciated. Thanks.

```
bar = Bar(result_df, values='Value', label='Label', legend='bottom_right',
                  stack='Stack', title="Title", bar_width=0.4,
                  color=color(columns='Stack', palette=self.get_colors(5), tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,resize,hover")
        hover = bar.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
        hover.tooltips=[("Stack", "@Stack"), (field_name, "@height{" + tooltip_fmt + "}")]


legend = Legend({
              "background_fill_alpha": {
                "value": 0
              },
              "background_fill_color": {
                "value": "#ffffff"
              },
              "border_line_alpha": {
                "value": 1.0
              },
              "border_line_cap": "butt",
              "border_line_color": {
                "value": "black"
              },
              "border_line_dash": [],
              "border_line_dash_offset": 0,
              "border_line_join": "miter",
              "border_line_width": {
                "value": 1
              },
              "glyph_height": 20,
              "glyph_width": 20,
              "label_height": 20,
              "label_standoff": 15,
              "label_text_align": "left",
              "label_text_alpha": {
                "value": 1.0
              },
              "label_text_baseline": "middle",
              "label_text_color": {
                "value": "#444444"
              },
              "label_text_font": "helvetica",
              "label_text_font_size": {
                "value": "10pt"
              },
              "label_text_font_style": "normal",
              "label_width": 50,
              "legend_padding": 10,
              "legend_spacing": 3,
              "legends": [],
              "level": "annotation",
              "location": "top_right"
            })
bar.add_legend(legend)
```

Comment: anyone could help or point to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the legend kwarg in the call to Bar as `legend=None`. That way, that legend never renders and when you add your custom one, it will be the only one. Just a hunch though.

Comment: Thanks ericmark26. Bokeh has just released a new version (in June) which supports putting legends outside of plot, so this issue is gone now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Did my suggestion work (my curiosity must be satisfied :) )?

Comment: My solution was similar to you, however I didn't set `legend=None` at first. I created Bar chart with the legends. Then I created a new legend object `new_legend=bar.legends[0]`, then I set `bar.legends[0]=None` and finally `bar.add_layout(new_legend, 'right')`. The reason was because I didn't know how to create legend manually for bar chart. The legend object needs the glyph (column in this case) to match between label and column and I could not extract each individual glyph from the bar. I hope I explain clear enough :)

Comment: How do you create the legend manually for the bar chart with a column?

Comment: I can't. I just let the bar chart creates its legend object. Then I copy that legend object to a new variable, disable the original bar's legend object finally I add the newly created legend to the bar and modify it as I see fit.